# MYSQL is not supporting a while loop containing more than one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install a procedure in Mysql 5.6 launching the command from mysql workbench (version 6).
I get a sintax error  with no apparent reason.
If I just remove one of the two assigments inside the while loop, then it would works.
How come i cannot put two statements inside the while?

```
DELIMITER //  

    CREATE PROCEDURE PROC (IN TABLE_  varchar(400))

BEGIN 
        DECLARE Statement varchar(400) DEFAULT ""; 
        DECLARE i INTEGER  DEFAULT 1; 
        DECLARE N INTEGER  DEFAULT 2; 

    while i <= N do 
      set Statement = 'a';
      set i = i+1;
    end while;
    END
       //
        DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '= 'a';   set i = i+1;   end while;    END' at line
>   10

Comment: Which mysql version are you using, mysql 8.0.18 has no Problems with this procedure

Comment: as written in the title i am trying to run it into Mysql 5.6

Comment: i can't see an error, maybe there are some characters. that don't show up here. copy the text from your Question and try it again.

Comment: I think it may be an issue with the DEFUALT "" in your Statement var declaration. If you leave off the DEFUALT Clause the initial value is NULL, So I would try using that instead. Since later when you set Statement using single quotes it may be throwing things off.

Comment: @jimmy_code there is no error when recreated locally.

Comment: i solved the problem: there were some special characters in between the lines.